# Can i declare a variable in Javascript like this?

Tags: javascript, variables, declare

Can i declare a variable like below?

var new_result_data_flag-- =1;

its giving error of ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

Comment: `its giving error` Looks like you have your answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of that? What is the *actual* and *real* problem you need to solve? Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as your question is an example of one.

Comment: No you canot , instead do like this  var new_result_data_flag__ =1;
     console.log(new_result_data_flag__);

Answer (score 0):

It's very basic question in the programming world, 'how to create and initialize the variable'

You can do like

```
var new_result_data_flag = 10

// if you want to subtract value from the same variable then do as below

new_result_data_flag -= 1 // is equals to new_result_data_flag = new_result_data_flag - 1

console.log(new_result_data_flag) // 9
```

Comment: my question is i want to add two minus symbol -- at the end of the variable. its giving me error Invalid left-hand side in assignment. FYI - i am talking about declaring a variable as per the given format.

Comment: why do you want `--` at the end of the variable? what is the use case of that? Do you want to show it on the screen?

Comment: @SantoshKumarSahu You can't use any arbitrary characters as part in your names, you have to follow the rules of the language.

Comment: I am calling a third party api which accepts the variable as per this format.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Not only can you not declare variables as such, you shouldn’t even want to if it was possible. It would be confusing for the reader.

The double minus operators perform a post/pre decrement operation, i.e., subtracts one from the variable and returns the decrement value (pre-decrement ) or the original value (post-decrement).
Your statement attempts to decrement a non-initialized value which would be confusing at best.
If you however simply need to have this naming scheme you could use an object property as such:

```
var bla = {};
bla['new_result_data_flag--'] = 'fluffy';
```

Comment: Appreciated, Thanks, This is exactly what i wanted and Solved.

Answer (score 0):

even you can use like this.

```
var new_result_data_flag_ =1;
console.log(new_result_data_flag_);
```

and my suggestion for variable declaration Names

1. Names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs.
2. Names must begin with a letter
3. Names can also begin with $ and _
4. Names are case sensitive (y and Y are different variables)
5. Reserved words (like JavaScript keywords) cannot be used as names

Comment: Appreciated, Thanks for your quick response.